# Problema ReactJS: forEach no es una funcion

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, foreach

estoy intentando mostrar por pantalla el nombre de 151 Pokémon que obtengo mediante una API, el código es el siguiente:

**Codigo actualizado con la respuesta de Dev. Joel:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

class HomeContainer extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=151&offset=151') //Solicitud api
            .then(({result}) => {
              //  console.log('aaa', result.data.results[0])
                crearCarta(result)
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error) //Solicitud error
            })
    }


    render() { //Renderizamos el html
        return (
            <div>
            <div className="navbar"></div>
            <header id="container"></header>
            </div>
            );
    }

}
function crearCarta(pokemons) {
    console.log('Dentro de Crear Carta -->   ', pokemons)
    const container = document.getElementById('container')
    console.log( 'Llamado a la API dentro de crearCarta' ,pokemons)

pokemons.forEach(id => {
        container.innerHTML += 
        ` 
        <header id="container">
        <h1>${pokemons.data.results[id].name}</h1>
        </header> 
        `
    }); 
}



export default HomeContainer
```

El problema es que me sale un error de forEach diciendo que no
es una función, no entiendo el por que y no logro solucionarlo. ¿A qué se debe este problema?

Gracias

Comment: ¿Cuál es el contenido de pokemons? Asegúrate de que el contenido sea lo que estás esperando. Si es posible, comparte lo que obtienes en `pokemons` dentro de la función `crearCarta()`.

Comment: El contenido de pokemons es el result, fijate que cuando llamo a la funcion desde  la clase, le paso por parametro result

Comment: Eso lo tenía claro, a lo que me refería es que pusieras un `console.log()` de dicha variable dentro de la función para asegurar que el contenido de la misma es un array -o al menos que contiene algún dato-.

Comment: Dale lo hare! Muchas gracias, a veces se me olvida el hecho de testear todo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está en que estás haciendo mal la desestructuración.
Axios retorna un response, y los datos de la respuesta los encuentras en `data`... `data` contiene la respuesta de la api... y la lista de pokemons está en el elemento `results` por lo tanto. la destructuración correcta sería

```js
axios.get('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=151&offset=151') //Solicitud api
.then(({data: {results: pokemons}}) => {
    console.log(pokemons);
    //crearCarta(pokemons);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```

Lo otro que veo es que crear carta recibe la lista de los pokemons, por lo tanto deberías cambiarla así

```
pokemons.forEach(pokemon => {
    //cada pokemon tiene la propiedad name y url
    container.innerHTML += 
    ` 
    <header id="container">
    <h1>${pokemon.name}</h1>
    </header> 
    `
});
```

Comment: Hola Pipe gracias por tu respuesta, y si quisiera manipular tambien las imagenes que me ofrece la API como lo tendria que hacer?

Comment: Solo debes agregar un elemento `<img src="${pokemon.url}" />`

Answer (score 1):

Tienes más de 1 error en el código.

1. El valor retornado de tu petición  `result` , es un objeto más no un array. Por lo cuál cuando intentas iterarlo con un [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) es imposible porque dicho método es propio de los arrays.
2. Al iterar en cada elemento, `asignas (=)` al innerHTML, más no añades `(+=)`, tal cuál solo mostraría por pantalla el último registro *(última iteración, ultima asignación)*

Solución.

1. Puede utilizar [desestructuración](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) para obtener el valor interno de data `.then(({data}) => {...}` y enviaría al método `crearCarta(data.results)`

   ```
   axios.get('...')
   .then(({data}) => {
       crearCarta(data.results)
    })
   ```
2. Añadir el contenido al `innerHTML` haciendo uso de `+=`

   ```
   pokemons.forEach(el => {
       container.innerHTML +=
       ` 
       <header id="container">
       <h1>${el.name}</h1>
       </header> 
       `
   });
   ```

Se puede mejorar el código pero esto debería solucionar el problema.

Comment: Hola Joel, muchas gracias por tu respuesta y tu explicación, aprendí mucho y leí los artículos, pero el problema no fue resuelto y no entiendo el por que, esto me esta volviendo loco, voy a actualizar el código que subí.

Comment: Me acabo de dar cuenta que me sale otro error, el cual es: forEach of Undefined

Comment: Le agrege un let variable = pokemons.forEach(id => { ........ pero sigue saliendo el error

Comment: @HatoriHanso según su pregunta editada, estoy 100% seguro que no ha leído mi respuesta porque ninguna de las dos correcciones está. (hay código que no he colocado en mi respuesta)

Comment: A decir verdad no entiendo por que pasaste a la funcion crearData por parametro data.results, yo tengo result en el .then, deberia pasar solo .result?

Comment: Entiendo que tenga que poner las cosas entre llaves para la desestructuracion, pero me da todo undefined.